# Nginx does not compress js

Tags: nginx, apache2, webserver

My Nginx webserver does not compress js files with gzip.

Config follows:

```
gzip on;
gzip_min_length  1100;
gzip_buffers  4 32k;
gzip_types text/plain application/xml text/css text/js text/xml application/x-javascript text/javascript application/json application/xml+rss;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 5;
```